# Where is the new toolchain based on old toolchain option in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gcc, mingw32

I know I found it before, but I can't seem to locate it now.

My end goal is to copy the linux-gcc toolchain configuration and change the default compiler/linker/path etc to work with my cross-compiler options and have it selectable as a toolchain.

The current workaround is to do all the editing in a skeleton project and copy it over and over.  I don't find it to be a 'good' solution, so I'm thinking this is a way to fix it myself.

The only part of this really required for an answer is how to copy the linux gcc toolchain to linux gcc2 for example.  I can do the rest of it myself.